# Given a generic object `ref`, can I discover the type of the object it is referencing?

Tags: nim-lang

Given (say) a `ref RootObj`, can I discover the type of the object it is referencing? (My experiments with `typetraits` etc. did not succeed...)

For example, given this:

```
import typetraits, typeinfo, system

type
  TypeA = object of RootObj
    field: int

var
  a : ref RootObj = TypeA.new # an instance of TypeA on the heap
```

Can I get the underlying type of `a`? `repr` seems to know, but `system.type` does not.

```
echo repr a      # output: ref 0x7f73e856c048 --> [field = 0]
echo a.type.name # output: ref RootObj
```

The `typeinfo` module seems not to solve this - it only deals with primitive types, and so can identify an object (`akObject`), but not the type of object.

I suspect there's another way, but what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no generic way to get the type name of a ref object in runtime. Such feature would require packing the type names into the binary, increasing its size, when in most cases this info is never used.

So if you really need some sort of runtime reflection, you'll have to implement it yourself.

However, there's a `-d:nimTypeNames` flag that enables type names into the binary, for GC debugging purposes. `repr` could reuse that info and should be easy to implement, so it's well worth a feature request. Still note this can be used only for debugging purposes.

Comment: I'd be happy with an identifier of some sort, it does not necessarily be the literal name. I don't know the implementation details, but assume Nim has to have something like this, in order to allow runtime dispatch and things like `deepCopy` to work?

Comment: Indeed, inheritable objects have a hidden `type` field in the beginning to allow runtime dispatch. And `ref`s point to a chunk of memory that has type info in the beginning, which is used for GC and `deepCopy`, but those are pretty hidden from the user code.